# Using .npmrc with npm publish actions

Tags: npm

We have a private NPM registry to which we are publishing our packages to, and have a `publishConfig` section in our projects package.json file which juts contains our registry url which gets picked up by our `npm publish` commands:

```
"publishConfig": {
    "registry": "xxxxxx"
  }
```

I would like to have this registry url read out from am .nprmc file rather than the package.json.

I have tried doing this, but when using `npm publish` I get:

> 400 - Repository with ID='xxx' is Read Only, but action was 'create'!

I figured this may be because I hadnt added my user details to my npmrc, which I have now done, but the problem still remains.

Is it possible for npm publish to use the details from an npmrc specifically?

Answer (score -1):

Just add the following to your .npmrc

```
registry=YOUR_REGISTRY
```